# AbstractClass ForeignKey reference to AbstractClass

Tags: django, abstract-class

I am building a compliance management system where I have the following requirements for most models in my project:

### My Requirements

- Users with certain roles can change fields, but this has to lead to a new "version" with a draft status
- After approval through certain other roles (i.e. managers) this version of the model has to be published
- History has to be accessible for all roles

### Current Situation

Because available django-apps did not meet all these requirements I created to following constuct:

1. Every model (e.g. Policy) has one **Master** and one **Detail** model.
2. The **Master** model has the following fields:

   - id
   - deleted
   - currentActiveDetail (ForeignKey)
3. The **Detail** model has the following fields:

   - id
   - majorVersion
   - minorVersion
   - author
   - masterModel (ForeignKey to **Master**)
   - user (ForeignKey to **auth.User**)
   - lifecycleStatus (Choice, i.e. 'Draft', 'Waiting Approval', 'Approved', 'Obsolete')
   - **a lot of content fields** (e.g. Description, Text,...)
   - **a lot of methods**

### Challenges/Questions

Because I have a lot of such use cases I want to make a MasterAbstractClass and a DetailAbstractClass but I can't find a solution to the following challanges:

1. How to "reserve" the ForeignKey fields in the abstract class (I know that I can't define them because there is no table in the database). I thought if using the contenttype framework but it seems to be inadequate because
2. it's a reference from one AbstractClass (**Master**) on one hand to another AbstractClass (**Detail**) on the other hand
3. for the user foreign key I know exactly to what model I want to reference

*EDIT 1:* Just realized that the 3rd challange is no problem at all, the following works:

```
class ContentLifecycleDetailClassModel (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)


class Test(ContentLifecycleDetailClassModel):
    pass
```

*CLI*

```
from polls.models import Test
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
test = Test()
user = User.objects.first()
test.author=user
test.save()
x = Test.objects.first()
print x.author.username # <-- Working
```

*EDIT 2:*
This issue was already discussed in 2009 but only a solution for one abstract class is used in one implementation which does not fit these needs: http://djangotricks.blogspot.co.at/2009/02/abstract-models-and-dynamicly-assigned.html

*EDIT 3:*
I ended up using the ContentType Framework to solve (1) and (2)

```
masterModel_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    masterModel_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    master_Model = GenericForeignKey('masterModel_type', 'masterModel_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the challenges by steps mentioned in the three edits. It was not the clean solution I expected but it is working..